# How do I pass additional startup parameter for play apps in cloudfoundry

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloud-foundry, playframework-2.1

When deploying a Play!2 app on cloudfoundry I would like to be able to specify at least one additional parameter to the startup command.

Currently it seems like cloudfoundry uses the start script created by Play2 without any arguments, but to override the default application configuration with specific production values I need it to be called with -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf

I couldn't find any way to do this, maybe through the manifest.yml but I wasn't able to find a specification for how to add this param.

Appart from this I was able to successfully deploy play 2.0 and play 2.1 apps to cloudfoundry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the source code for the cloudfoundry tooling I found out that the vcap-staging plugin for play does not honor the "command" attribute in manifest.ml nor does it ask for one. It automatically assume that the application will be started with the "start" (see [line 10 in plugin.rb](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-staging/blob/master/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb#L10)).

However, it [does honor](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-staging/blob/master/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb#L41) the JAVA_OPTS environment variable.

In the end, I was able to do

```
vmc set-env JAVA_OPTS "-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf"
```

And get it working as I wanted.

Comment: Thanks, Jean ! Environment variable solution works great !

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is extracting and uploading the built zip as a standalone app. As you may already tried, put the argument right after the start script as the startup command line when prompted. Although this will bring a certain problem that you cannot take the advantage of the CF provide feature  "auto-reconfiguration" for the services bound and you have to have separate configurations in order to deploy on cloud.

Comment: I have not been able to start the app when uploading as a standalone app, even though is has no external dependency apart from a jvm and the unziped archive starts just fine locally.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did you run vmc push under the folder unzipped from the built zip? What was the error?

Comment: Starting app2... FAILED
CFoundry::AppStagingError: 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed:
 Staging plugin failed: /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/7.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod': No such file or directory - /var/vcap/data/stager/tmp/d20130129-8445-gcr8v1/staged/app/start (Errno::ENOENT

Comment: I finally found that vmc push --name app2 --path dist/app-1.0/ works  when cd dist; vmc push --name app2 --path /app-1.0/ doesnt. That solutions requires changes to the release package though. While this can be automated, I prefer the solution of passing the arguments through set-env...